# How to make good reproducible SAS examples?

Tags: sas

SAS programs are generally written in such a way that they are specific to a particular dataset.  How can a SAS programmer create a reproducible example of SAS code, either to show a problem with their code to someone who does not have access to the original data, or to embed some data - whether real or artificial - in the example, so that someone else can easily run the same SAS program?

Comment: This appears to be a question that is more suitable for [meta], as it is not an actual programming question, but more about better use of SO for SAS questions and is asking for opinions or options.

Comment: The URLs of the Pandas and R guides I cited (both highly recognized by the community) are on SO, *not on Meta*. I thought there must be some good reasons for such "make good reproducible examples" questions to not be migrated. So I decided to follow the de-facto recognized status of these posts first. Of course I'd humbly accept senior contributors' decision on whether to migrate this post or not.

Comment: So - two things.  One - I think this is fine here, if it's not *specific* to Stack Overflow.  If it's specific to Stack Overflow, then it belongs in meta.  Two - OP (@BillHuang), you have posted a question and a bunch of answers, and they're really not exactly aimed at creating reproducible examples in here; you shouldn't post answers in questions, and you need to think about what you're actually aiming for here a bit more I think.

Comment: Really, basically none of what you posted probably should be in the ultimate question - let's get a good question, that just asks what it wants to have in it, so that people searching can find it as a good search target, and then get an answer.  I'll propose an edit here in a moment; if you don't agree with the edit, we can discuss more, maybe in a chatroom.  Then, I'll post my suggested answer, and you can post any of the above that you want there as answers as well.

Comment: Finally - this probably should be a CW (Community Wiki), since it's not exactly a normal question/answer.  It might be better to have a single, curated (CW) answer rather than separate ones, though it mostly depends on what exactly you're aiming for here.

Comment: Hi @Joe, a few points. (1) I added the reference back to address where the title and question itself came from. (2) I agree this post would be better transferred to CW. But now the CW box is gone when I edit. Is it possible for you tp act as a moderator to do it?

Comment: @BillHuang The reference is neither necessary nor appropriate; it is meta-information and thus irrelevant.  The question isn't copy/pasted from somewhere else, and so is fine to stand on its own - where you got the idea is important only to you. :)  I'm not a (diamond) moderator, just a normal community member with the same moderating power as any 10k+ rep member, so no, I can't make it CW - you'd have to flag for a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to produce a reproducible SAS example is to embed sample data using the [`datalines`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=vdmmlcdc&cdcVersion=8.1&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0114gachtut3nn1and4ap8ke9nf.htm&locale=en) or `cards` statement.

```
data have;
  input var1 var2 $;
datalines;
1 A
2 B
3 B
;;;;
run;
```

Some notes:

- Datalines must be the last statement of the data step, immediately prior to run
- If the datalines contain a semicolon, use `datalines4` or `cards4` and then terminate the block with four semicolons.  Otherwise, one is sufficient.
- Datalines may not be contained in a macro - they must be in open code
- You may include a `infile datalines;` statement anywhere in the data step prior to the input statement, in order to modify the datalines to have a different delimiter than space, or use most other `infile` options.

In producing a reproducible example for a question on a forum such as this, it is best to include both `have` and `want` datasets (or otherwise clearly labelled datasets indicating the before-code and after-code).

Comment: Nit pick.  The RUN: statement here is NOT part of the data step.  The data step ends with the end of the in line data. The INFILE statement must appear before the first INPUT statement.

Comment: @Tom "Must be the last statement of the data step" is entirely accurate there. :)  And sure, I'll add the infile mention - you should feel free to edit such things in the future if you want, you're certainly able to :)

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible examples in SAS are often possible without introducing any extra data, due to the existence of the [`SASHELP`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=grstatproc&docsetTarget=p0jxq3ea4njtvnn1xnj4a7s37pyz.htm&locale=en) library.

This library contains numerous datasets that can be used as example data, including the commonly used `SASHELP.CLASS` and `SASHELP.CARS` datasets.  These can be used to show simple examples of SAS code that either fit well with the data provided, or do not depend on the particulars of a dataset.  They are available on all SAS installations.